# Optimize a query with LEFT JOIN with multiple WHERE Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Is it at all possible to optimize the query below, which was produced today:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,country,c.id 
id_employer,c.comp_name,c.show_comp_name,comp_type,b.id countryid,if(now() 
<a.hotjob_expire, true, false) is_hot 
FROM j5xap_jbjobs_job a 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_country b ON a.id_country = b.id 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_employer c ON a.employer_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_custom_field_value cv ON cv.jobid=a.id 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_comp_type d ON c.id_comp_type = d.id 
WHERE (a.job_title LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR a.state LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR a.city LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR b.country LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR c.comp_name LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR cv.value LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR cv.valuetext LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR a.short_desc LIKE '%Web developer%' 
   OR a.long_desc LIKE '%Web developer%') 
   OR (a.job_title LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR a.state LIKE '%kannur%'
   OR a.city LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR b.country LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR c.comp_name LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR cv.value LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR cv.valuetext LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR a.short_desc LIKE '%kannur%' 
   OR a.long_desc LIKE '%kannur%') 
   AND a.id_job_spec =441 AND a.id_job_spec 
   IN (SELECT id FROM j5xap_jbjobs_job_spec WHERE id_category='63') 
   AND 
   a.is_active='y' AND a.publish_date <= '2017-07-07 00:00:00' 
   AND
   expire_date  >= '2017-07-07 00:00:00' 
   AND 
   expire_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
   ORDER BY is_hot DESC, a.is_featured DESC, a.publish_date DESC, a.id                      
   DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

I have been looking at it extensively but I am a little out of ideas. Left Joins have to be used in this context. I have included multi column indexes on the tables and on the fields that are being retrieved from the SELECT clause.

Are there any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the `EXPLAIN select ...` output

Comment: Although 'x%' can use an index, '%x' cannot, so performance is always going to be limited for this kind of query.

Comment: I suspect you have a bug in `... AND a.id_job_spec =441 AND a.id_job_spec IN (SELECT ... )`  Maybe you wanted `OR`?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an index on:  `j5xap_jbjobs_job(id_job_spec, is_active, publish_date, is_expire)`.  For all the other tables, you need an index on the join keys.

This should allow the filtering to take place using an index, which should be a win for performance.